# phpDocumentor applied to some functions

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there any way you can make phpDocumentor generate docs only for some specific functions (even if all of them have the right docblock) ? Maybe there is a special tag for this ?

Update: I can't use @ignore because I just need to generate docs for a small amount of function/methods and most of them have docblocks. Imagine a framework. The goal is to make docs just for extra dev. methods because the core should be clear for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the functions/methods into a seperated PHP file. eg: functions.php
Than run PhpDoc on that file.

The other possibility is to write the doc by yourself, because i think that it is a end user documentation.

I hope that will help you.